# Multiple angled lines are converging instead of parallel (tikz)

Tags: tikz-pgf, draw, parallel, angle

I'm trying to draw a simple diagram where an angled grid is incident on a plane. I have two questions;

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \filldraw[fill = blue!50!white, draw = black]
            (2.2,-0.2) -- (3.8,-0.2) -- (3.8, 0.2) -- (2.2, 0.2) -- cycle;  %Plane surface, centred on (3,0)
        \draw[<-,  line width = 1.6] (3,0) -- (140:3);                      %Incident wave vector
        \foreach \y in {1, 2, 3, 4}
            \draw[dotted] (3, 0.5*\y) -- (140:3);
        \draw[->, line width = 1.6] (3,0) -- (3,2);                     %Normal-to-surface vector
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Firstly, this code produces converging lines instead of parallel lines (despite specifying 140 degrees) What am I doing wrong?

Secondly, how would I go about adding lines pointing vertically, but stemming from the axis defined in the first \draw command?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)! For your first question, you probably want relative coordinates in the second coordinate of the `\draw` command in the loop (e.g. `\draw (3, 0.5*\y) -- ++(140:3);`).

Comment: @Max that makes them parallel, but they're now at a different angle! I'm not sure what I've done wrong here

Comment: Make the first `\draw` also using `--++`

Comment: @Hunter please see the [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/488398/74459) of marmot below which uses some geometry to calculate which angle to use to be parallel to your arrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lines are not parallel because you draw them to `(140:3)` rather than, say, `++(<angle>:3)`. Orthogonal lines can be drawn with `calc`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \filldraw[fill = blue!50!white, draw = black]
            (2.2,-0.2) -- (3.8,-0.2) -- (3.8, 0.2) -- (2.2, 0.2) -- cycle;  %Plane surface, centred on (3,0)
        \draw[<-,  line width = 1.6] (3,0) coordinate (X)-- (140:3)
         foreach \X [count=\Y] in {0.4,0.6,0.8,1} {coordinate[pos=\X] (p\Y)};                     %Incident wave vector
        \foreach \Y in {1,...,4} 
        {\draw[dotted] (p\Y)  -- ($ (p\Y)!2cm!90:(X) $);}
        \draw[dotted] let \p1=($(140:3)-(3,0)$),\n1={atan2(\y1,\x1)}
        in foreach \y in {1, 2, 3, 4} {(3, 0.5*\y) -- ++(\n1:6)};
        \draw[->, line width = 1.6] (3,0) -- (3,2);                     %Normal-to-surface vector
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Max kindly pointed out you may want something different:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \filldraw[fill = blue!50!white, draw = black]
            (2.2,-0.2) -- (3.8,-0.2) -- (3.8, 0.2) -- (2.2, 0.2) -- cycle;  %Plane surface, centred on (3,0)
        \draw[<-,  line width = 1.6] (3,0) coordinate (X)-- (140:3)
         foreach \X [count=\Y] in {0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,1} {coordinate[pos=\X] (p\Y)};                     %Incident wave vector
        \foreach \Y in {1,...,5} 
        {\draw[dotted] (p\Y)  -- ++ (0,2.5);}

        \draw[dotted] let \p1=($(140:3)-(3,0)$),\n1={atan2(\y1,\x1)}
        in foreach \y in {1, 2, 3, 4} {(3, 0.5*\y) -- ++(\n1:6)};
        \draw[->, line width = 1.6] (3,0) -- (3,2);                     %Normal-to-surface vector
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Quickest Tikzpert in the wild west! I do believe that the OP wants the vertical grid lines to originate from the angled arrow, but still pointing straight up. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Max Thanks a lot!!

Comment: That's perfect, thank you! I'm a little lost on the notation, specifically what [count = \Y] is used for, and what "p" means. I've been digging through the manual but it's getting to the point I'm not taking anything in

Comment: @Hunter `count` counts the items and is explained on p. 976 in section **87 Repeating Things: The Foreach Statement** of the pgfmanual.